# regex: match white-spaces that do not enclosed in []

Tags: regex

For example, for this string,

```
div.img-wrapper img[title="Hello world"]
```

I want to match the first space but not the second space (which is enclosed in []). What is the regex?

Comment: Sort of. I am working on a CSS selector to xpath converter. Zend framework ships with a CSS selector to xpath converter, but it is buggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression will do the job by using a look ahead assertion.

```
_(?>[^[\]]*(\[|$))
```

The underscore represents a space. This expression does not support nested brackets because regular expression are not powerful enough to express nested matched structures.

```
_          Match the space and
(?>        assert that it is not inside brackets
  [^[\]]*  by matching all characters except brackets
  (        followed by either
    \[     an opening bracket (a space inside brackets
           will have a closing bracket at this position)
    |      or
    $      or no more characters (end of line).
  )
)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another (and more beautiful) solution using a negative look ahead assertion.

```
_(?![^[\]]*])
```

It asserts that the next bracket after a space is not a closing bracket.

Comment: _(?![^[\]]*]) is exactly what I am using. It can assert that the _ does not have following ], but it can assert that it does not have preceding [. But anyway, it servers the propose. I just want to know how to combine lookahead assertion with lookbehide assertion

Comment: The negative look behind assertion for no opening bracket has to be something like (?<!\\[[^[\\]]*) but if I correctly remember using + and * is not allowed in look behind assertions. In consequence it is probably not possible to use a negative look behind assertion to check for no opening bracket.