# splitting a string and keep some white spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like

```
test = 'a=1 b=2 c=[2 3] d=[3 4 5]'
```

and would like to extract the following substrings:

```
a=1
b=2
c=[2 3]
d=[3 4 5]
```

`test.split()` works very well for the first two substrings, but does not work for the rest.

Is there a simple way in Python to extract the substring in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2892908/9997212):

```
import re

test = 'a=1 b=2 c=[2 3] d=[3 4 5]'
print(re.split(r' (?![^[\]]*])', test))
# Outputs ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=[2 3]', 'd=[3 4 5]']
```

---

If you want to handle the case where

```py
test = 'a=1    b=2        c=[2 3]     d=[3 4 5]'
```

you can replace the `re.split` line with

```py
print(re.split(r' +(?![^[\]]*])', test))
#                 ^ add a plus here to match one or
#                   more spaces between each substring
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Seems this is using some Perl syntax and I am not familiar with it. What should I do if there might be more white spaces or tab between the substring? Thanks you again.

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if this solves your problem. If you wish, Python provides [a tutorial on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve all the substrings of the form `character=number` or `character=[number number ...]`, you can do:

```
import re

test = 'a=1 b=2 c=[2 3] d=[3 4 5]'
groups = re.findall(r'([a-z]=(([0-9]+)|(\[[0-9]+( [0-9]+)*\])))', test)

for group in groups:
  print(group[0])

'''
Output:

a=1
b=2
c=[2 3]
d=[3 4 5]
'''
```

This approach is robust to, for example, changes in the format the data is in.